# Draggable Popup Modal window overflow issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

there is a draggable popup modal that I am using in the project. However, when I drag anywhere on this draggable popup modal ,in the browser window as much as I drag it disappears. However, what I want is that this sustainable popup modal does not overflow on the browser (window) in any way.
It is locked in the window and shows all.To summarize, I want to prevent the dragging popup modal scroll from opening, and I also want it to remain fixed within the window size. I would be glad if you could help me.

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal --> 
</div>

<script>
        $('.modal').modal({ keyboard: false,
                           show: true
        });
        // Jquery draggable
        $('.modal-dialog').draggable({
            handle: ".modal-header"
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy, you should look at jqUI draggable to know what to do.

Use `containment:parent` or `containment:body`

there is many other functions you could look at [here](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#default)

```js
        $('.modal').modal({ keyboard: false,
                           show: true
        });
        // Jquery draggable
        $('.modal-dialog').draggable({
            handle: ".modal-header",
            containment: "parent"
        });
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal --> 
</div>
```

Comment: I searched but couldn't find it. Thank you @Alen.Toma

Comment: glad i could help, mark this as answer if its help you solv the problem

Comment: Yes, I checked, I was very satisfied again